# How to write text based on RANK function

Tags: excel

I understand the RANK function, just not sure how to add the text based on said RANK.

- If A1 equals 10 than write "10 is the best"
- If A5 equals 5 thank write "5 is average"
- If A2 equals 1 than write "1 is the worst"

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP()` along with `RANK()` function. Put samples in post.

Comment: https://exceljet.net/articles/index-and-match should do